# Как бот в телеграмме может подождать ввод числа пользователем?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Пишу бота для Телеграмм на telebot(pytelegrambotapi) и вообщем-то бот пишет человеку, чтобы он ввел длину паролей и человек не успевает ничего ввести как бот продолжает дальше выполнять код, который приведет к ошибке.

```
def next_step2(*args):
    if use_english == 'нет' and use_figures == 'нет' use_symbols == 'нет':
        error_settings()
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''
            ❍ Напишите длину паролей \n  \n
            ➮ Макс. 150 символов, минимум 1''')

        length = message.text # Здесь необходима какая-то задержка, потому что человек не успевает ничего ввести как сразу же бот проверяет следущую строку.

        if length.isdigit() == True:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Кол-во символов в паролях будет: ' +str(length))
        else:
            error001()

def error001(*args):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''
        ❍ Вы написали что-то другое.. 
        \n ➮ Напишите длину паролей, макс. 150 символов, минимум 1
        \n ➮ Или нажмите на кнопку, чтобы сгенерировать длину 
        ''' .format(name))
```

Comment: Вместо ``if length.isdigit() == True`` достаточно просто ``if length.isdigit()``. Кстати,  и ² и ³ и т.п. тоже типа digit, но вряд ли такой ввод вас устроит.

Comment: Не совсем понял, о чём это вы - кстати, и ² и ³ и т.п. тоже типа digit, но вряд ли такой ввод вас устроит.

Comment: Если кто- нибудь введёт символ ², то проверка isdigit() выдаст положительный результат.

Comment: isdigit() в любом случае выведет True если текст будет состоять только из цифр, а проверка на, то что пользователь ввел от 1 до 150 у меня уже есть. Только её работа невозможна до тех, пор пока я не узнаю, как сделать так, чтобы бот подождал каким-то образом ввод числа

Comment: ² это не цифра в общем понимании. 2 - цифра. А ² - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно организовать взаимодействие таким образом:

1. бот получает команду
2. бот посылает запрос на ввод числа
3. бот получает число в *новом* сообщении
4. бот сохраняет полученное число

Вам нужно ждать после шага 2. Важный момент, это что ожидание должно происходить не в обработчике шага 1. Т.е. в обработчике команды, бот должен

1. послать запрос на ввод числа
2. запомнить, что такому-то пользователю он послал запрос

Запоминание нужно, чтобы, когда бот получит следующее сообщение от этого пользователя (в отдельном обработчике, т.е. в функции с `@bot.message_handler'), то чтобы бот знал, что это сообщение нужно трактовать как ответ на вопрос.

Самый простейший вариант, это сохранить `message.chat.id` в коллекцию типа так:

```
waiting_for_password_length_reply = set()

def next_step2(..):
    ...
    waiting_for_password_length_reply.add(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''
            ❍ Напишите длину паролей \n  \n
            ➮ Макс. 150 символов, минимум 1''')
```

Ну и теперь в новом обработчике можно сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in waiting_for_password_length_reply, content_types=['text'])
def handle_password_length_reply(message):
    try:
       length = int(message.text) 
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Кол-во символов в паролях будет: ' +str(length))
       waiting_for_password_length_reply.remove(message.chat.id)
    except ValueError as e:
       error001()
```

Comment: При нажатии на какую-либо кнопку в коде происходит ошибка: 
  File "telegrambot.py", line 72, in <lambda>
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in waiting_for_pas
sword_length, content_types=['text'])
NameError: name 'waiting_for_password_length' is not defined"

Comment: Если присвоить переменной waiting_for_password_length, то есть написать так waiting_for_password_length = 0 в начале кода, будет ошибка:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\telebot\__init__.py", line 2024, in <lambda>
    'func': lambda msg: filter_value(msg)
  File "telegrambot.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in waiting_for_pas
sword_length, content_types=['text'])
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: Если сделать так в начале кода waiting_for_password_length = '0', будет другая ошибка:

  File "telegrambot.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in waiting_for_pas
sword_length, content_types=['text'])
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"

Comment: Это же набросок кода :) Там была опечатка `waiting_for_password_length`, а должно быть `waiting_for_password_length_reply`, т.е. так как называется переменная вначале. Исправил